# Segmentation fault in JNI code when calling "CallIntMethod(jclass, jmethodId, ...)

Tags: jvm, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

My JNI code consists of calling some java functions (.jar file) from a C++ main.

The code compiles well, but during execution i get :

**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

i ran GNU gdb to debug and i found the following during the call of this method :

```
if(mid != 0) {
doub = env->CallIntMethod(cls,mid,10);
```

**Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.**
    **0x00000000678856ed in jvm!JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs ()**
    **from /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll**

I also checked if the class is found (JNI FindClass function) and if the JVM is created (JNI_CreateJavaVM function) through the return value, and everything seems to be just fine.

At the end of the debugging the threads exit with code 35584 :

**[Thread 4632.0x1304 exited with code 35584]**

I didn't find anything about this value except that it implies a problem in the path to something required by the executable ... Any ideas about this ? 
I specified the path for the .jar file as following :

```
char op[] = "-Djava.class.path=D:\\path\\tojar/MyJar.jar;D:\\path\\toclass";
options[0].optionString = op;
```

Thank you StackOverflowers :)

ps : if you think that posting the code can help please notify me in the comments !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CallIntMethod` expects the first argument to be the receiver (i.e. `this`) object.
When the method you call is static, use `CallStaticIntMethod`.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you when you talked about static methods I forgot that in case they're not, you should declare a new object with the id of the constructor ! 
This object will be the receiver in CallIntMethod()

So in case I want to call non-static functions i should write the following : 

     'mid = env->GetMethodId(cls,"<init>","()V");'
     'obj = env->NewObject(cls,mid);'